# Question about use and meaning of "...kind of effect"

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions

> Today we’re going to try to give you some useful tips on how to start and stop smoothly. From a starting standpoint, to an acceleration standpoint, you have to remember that it doesn’t take a whole lot of pressure on the pedal to get the car to accelerate. Just a nice, smooth touch will usually do what you need. My recommendation is a very, very, smooth, soft, touch on the pedal, and let the car gradually build speed. If you need a little bit more acceleration, you’re going to gradually push your foot down a little harder on the pedal. You don’t want to push too much on the pedal when you first start. If you’re doing that, that will cause your car to have a jerking **kind of effect**

Could you make some similar expressions to the following sentence using **...kind of effect** , so that I can get the meaning of it.

- if you do that, it will cause your car to have a jerking **kind of effect.**

My try

-If you propose a girl early, it will have that saddness kind of effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the perfect word would be 'sensation'.

Sensation is a word for an effect or feeling which is weird, awesome, or unnatural. It can also be substituted seamlessly for 'kind of effect'.

> - The rollercoaster travelled at what seemed to be the speed of sound, at a hundred metres above the ground, giving us the **sensation/kind of effect** of flying through the air.
> - If you do that, it will cause your car to have a sort of jerking **sensation**.